# I am new to Linux, and the fonts are huge

Tags: fonts, screen, display-resolution

I have tried making them smaller in Settings>Fonts but nothing changes.  Any ideas?
I am using Kubuntu 16.04; the suggestion to check screen resolution appears to be the answer.  It is stuck at 800x600.  Xrandr shows this as the setting, the min, and the max.  No list of options as some responses show.  Tried
1.click KDE start icon. 2.select System Settings.
3. select Startup and Shutdown. 4. click Add Program...
5. enter 'xrandr -s 1024x768' in the text box. 6. be sure the "run in Terminal" checkbox is checked  7.follow the rest of the prompts to set it as a startup command; nothing changed after reboot x 3.

Comment: Give more information about your system. What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Also, what is your screen resolution? [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1329920/edit) your question to post these information.

Comment: as a possible option: switch your theme.

Comment: Kubuntu 16.04 LTS was released on 21st April 2016, and was supported for Kubuntu for a period of year 3 years. * Kubuntu 16.04 LTS support therefore ends 21st April 2019, and users are invited to upgrade to 18.04 LTS, or perform a fresh install of that or newer release.

Answer (score 1):

You can install gnome tweaks. In there there are some extra configuration options including fonts. You can change values for interface text, documents, etc. and scale it too.

Comment: Upgrading to 20.04 has fixed the resolution issue.  Case closed.